# D3 Bar wont display

Tags: d3.js

In this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tobedoh/edit?html,output) I'm using cdn to get d3 version 3 to display a rect but it only shows using the html svg tags but with D3. What am I missing? Thank you.

Here is the html mark up for the rect using d3.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Drawing SVG Shapes with D3</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>SVG Bar</h3>
  <svg>
    <rect width="50" height="200" style="fill:blue"/>
  </svg>

  <h3>D3 Bar</h3>
  <script>
    d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .append("rect")
        .attr("widt",50)
        .attr("height",200)
        .style("fill","blue");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you mean to use `.attr("width",` rather than `.attr("widt",`

Comment: Oh man! What an overlook. Thank you. That was it.

Comment: Thank you Andrew.